# Technologies for Streaming Audio Over a Wifi Network?

Tags: wireless-networking, streaming

What technologies (hardware/software) are available for streaming audio in realtime (with some latency, of course) over a Wifi network? Although I'm using mostly Macs, I would like something that any client can access (especially smart phones that can access Wifi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) can stream over WiFi or the internet.  I have it running at home so I can listen to my music over the air from work on my PC or from my Android phone, but there is also an iPhone app.

Comment: interesting link http://alternativeto.net/software/subsonic/

Answer (score 1):

For the Mac/iPhone combo the tool you need is [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/). It can use an AirPort Express station or you can install the 'server' component on the machines you'd like to play through. It has a free companion app that will let your iPhone/iPod Touch become the 'speaker' as well.

Comment: The computers running as speakers for Airfoil can be anything. You can download the server-side software from the vendor's site.

Comment: I'm looking through the site now. So the client list would be Mac, PC, Linux, or iOS only? I can't seem to understand the site too well: what about Android and other smartphones? Seems not

Comment: yeah, talked to their support: no android. "Airfoil can transmit audio from your computer to an AirPort Express Base Station, Apple TV, or any other computer - including Mac, PC, Linux and/or iOS device (iPhone, iPod touch, iPad) - that is running our free Airfoil Speakers client."

Comment: Note that Airfoil has a (minimum) 2s latency.

Answer (score 1):

For me: ices + icecast on the ubuntu server side; any stream player on the client side (e.g. XiiaLive Lite on the Android)

Comment: I'll be checking this out. Any links you put up before I check it out would be greatly appreciated :)